# How to Search Stl List Item With Alghorithm Find()

Tags: list, stl, find

I have a list with nodes with this structure:

```
private:
    char namefield[30];
    char tam[3];
    char type[1];
};
```

I want to find and element with the find function from alghorithm class but I want to do it with the namefield property of the item, the `find` function has an item to find as a parameter but the thing is that I want to send a property of the node instead of the node itself..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find_if` function http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/. You define a predicate (comparison function) for your struct that returns true if the namefields of both structures are true. 
Or something like that

```
class Cmp : public std::unary_function<mystruct, bool> {
    std::string m_str;
public: 
    Cmp(const std::string &str) : m_str(str) {}
    bool operator()(const mystruct &val) const {
        return m_str.compare(val.namefield) ==0;
    }
};

std::find_if(cont.begin(), cont.end(), Cmp("foo"));
```

where `cont` is the container of your struct